# If the origin of photons is different then how can their speed be same?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

If the wavelength of UV , Infrared , X rays etc is different then can the speed of photons present in respective rays is constant (i-e c=38000000000) ?

Comment: "c=38000000000" - what is this number? What are the units? Note that speed of electromagnetic radiation (including photons) is constant _in vacuum_ only, and _defined_ to be exactly 299,792,458  m/s. This is used to fix the definition of the meter.

Answer (score 3):

Notice, the speed of the photon is constant for all the wavelengths which is given as $$c=f\cdot \lambda=3\times 10^8\ \mathrm{ms^{-1}}$$ 
If the wavelength $(\lambda)$ of E.M. wave changes then its frequency ($f$) also changes while the product (i.e. speed of photon) of $\lambda$ & $f$ remains constant.

Comment: Yeah ! I had also the same view but I've read that the wavelength of X ray is 10^-14 , and its frequency is 10^23 so the speed becomes 10^9 not 3 10^8

Comment: Xrays do't have a "single" wavelength, and the numbers you read are "order of magnitude". That is - they are given in powers of 10 without a number in front. Usually that is an indication that the number just gives you a "rough idea of how big something is". I might say "humans are $10^0$ meters tall", but I would not say "humans are 1.00 m tall". The two statements have very different implied precision.